# "Live" leaderboard ("toplist") for backend performance (PHP + Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, live, leaderboard

we are stuck with our plans regarding to create a "Live" leaderboard for our game. We want a leaderboard that can track progress and being performance friendly.

So far what we've done is to create a way to only insert new stats in a mysql-table, and not to update anything. The reason is that we never want to remove old stats, because of the progress indication in each placement-row. Also, with only insertion we're not locking the table (mysql).

So here's the thing; Players will be able to share ranking, and each insert to the table is for just one point each time. - When we add this point, we want to return those users who's been affected so we can notify them about the "leaderboard change".

Here's our though; A mysql table that holds these columns: 
  `id`, `user_id`, `rank`, `week`, `month`, `year`, `points`, `placement_id`, `created`

Our thought is if we have a column called "placement_id" that always holds a new ID everytime that #rank is edited, we can keep track of this. But what we've discovered is that if the user leaves a rank, the rest underneath that placement have to follow one rank up, if it's empty. And it's here everything goes to hell pretty much.

Does anyone have any idea how to think regarding this? Since we dont want to update the rows, for performance reasons when the leaderboard has thousands of players, what can we do?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** and we dont work from specification unless large amounts of cash are involved

Comment: Again with the **upvote on a bad question** Please stop it

Comment: @RiggsFolly He is asking the approach..

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Then its Off Topic

Comment: @RiggsFolly How is it Off Topic? Im giving clear instructions about our intentions. Please provide me with a question instead so I can make this thread better, instead of complaining. As you can see on my points here in SO, I don't have much and Im still learning how to elaborate as good as possible,

Comment: Dont worry about it, it will take 4 other people to agree with me before the question gets closed. However as you have received nothing in the way of answers after an hour, its either _off topic_, or _far to big a question_ for anybody to ponder for long enough to come up with a good answer, based on the fact we all have other things to do in order to pay the rent.

Comment: @Theo Please check this..

Comment: @Quentin Please check this